# What is the for loop for this dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python

I have the following dict comprehension but I don't know how to convert it back to for loop.

```
Value = [1,2,3,4,5]
Key = ['a','b','c','a','c']
{k: [Value[i] for i in [j for j, x in enumerate(Key) if x == k]] for k in set(Key)}
```

I tried:

```
d1 = {}
for k in set(Key):
    for i in [j for j, x in enumerate(Key) if x == k]:
        d1[k].append(Value[i])
```

But this is clearly wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: What is `Key`? Also, what is `Value`?

Comment: sorry. I added them. Key and Value are two lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create `d1[k]` as a list.

```
for k in set(Key):
    d1[k] = []
    ...
```

---

Although, the inner list comprehension is redundant: all it really does is rename `j` to `i`. You can unwrap it too:

```
for k in set(Key):
    d1[k] = []
    for i, x in enumerate(Key):
        if x == k:
            d1[k].append(Value[i])
```

---

That said, this whole thing is overcomplicated and can be done much more easily with `zip`:

```
d1 = {}
for k, v in zip(Key, Value):
    values = d1.setdefault(k, [])
    values.append(v)
print(d1)  # -> {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 5]}
```

Although, if `Key` and `Value` aren't guaranteed to be the same length, this may fail silently. To avoid that, in Python 3.10+ you could use `zip(Key, Value, strict=True)`, otherwise you could rework it to be `for i, k in enumerate(Key) ... values.append(Values[i])`.

*Note: In Python 3.7+, this solution [preserves insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/4518341) where yours doesn't due to the `set` conversion.*

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what `Value` is previously declared as but the dict comprehension is equivalent to:

```py
d1 = {}
for k in set(Key):
    d1[k] = []

    for i in [j for j, x in enumerate(Key) if x == k]:
        d1[k].append(Value[i])
```

You need to set `d1[k]` to an empty list first.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code in the question:

```
{k: [Value[i] for i in [j for j, x in enumerate(Key) if x == k]] for k in set(Key)}
```

It might be a pretty great one-liner, but it's not immediately obvious to anyone what it does. In fact I spent a bit of time puzzling out *how* it works, and I still don't fully understand it yet.

In this case, I would suggest simplifying it, perhaps by splitting it over a few extra lines, just so that it's clearer for others and also  for yourself what is going on. For example, consider the following example with `defaultdict`, which is a subclass of `dict`:

```py
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(Key, Value):
    my_dict[k].append(v)
```

Result of `my_dict`, which again contains the same contents:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 5]})
```